# Quarkus& IntelliJ Run Tests in DevMode

Tags: intellij-idea, quarkus

How can I run the test driven tests for Quarkus in IntelliJ?

If i enter a "r" in the IntelliJ console nothing happens. If i try to execute it with "Shift + Enter" IntelliJ tells me that this view is read only.

Is there any way to execute the quarkus cmd commands directly in the IntelliJ console?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this help: https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing ? See also https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#test-from-ide

Comment: By console do you mean the terminal or something else?

Comment: I mean the IntelliJ Terminal Window, where the server is started (Manually I can execute all Tests)